# Invalid version of spring-jpa

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

In my project I have three model files- User, Appointment and Notification. There are three repository interfaces each implements CRUDRepository. Service and Controller class are also present. While executing the project i am getting  two errors:
1. No spring Webinitializer detected on classpath.
2. exception while creating bean.
here is stack trace:

```
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further     details.
Feb 14, 2018 8:54:00 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Feb 14, 2018 8:54:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext    listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance  of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating   bean with name 'EHealthController': Injection of autowired dependencies  failed; nested exception is    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.cl3.service.EHealthService   com.cl3.controller.EHealthController.eservice; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'EHealthService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.cl3.model.UserRepository com.cl3.service.EHealthService.uRepo; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.findPropertyForMethod(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/beans/PropertyDescriptor;
```

Many answers on stackoverflow suggested that error is due to invalid version of spring-jpa and spring data. I tried to change the version of spring, but did not help. Which version of spring and spring-jpa should I use? Do I need to add some other dependency?

ehealth-dispacter-servlet.xml

```
<beans 
xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
xsi:schemaLocation=
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd">


<context:component-scan base-package="com.cl3.controller" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cl3.model" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cl3.service" />

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/pages/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
    <property name="generateDdl" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.cl3.model"/>
</bean>

 <bean id="transactionManager" 
class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven/>

 <jpa:repositories base-package="com.cl3.model"/>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/cl3" />
    <property name="username" value="ucan" />
    <property name="password" value="ucan" />
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="eservice" class="com.cl3.service.EHealthService">
    <property name="uRepo" ref="uRepo"></property>
    <property name="nRepo" ref="nRepo"></property>
    <property name="aRepo" ref="aRepo"></property>
</bean>

  <bean id="uRepo"  class="com.cl3.model.UserRepository">
</bean>
 <bean id="nRepo" class="com.cl3.model.NotificationRepository">
</bean>
<bean id="aRepo"  class="com.cl3.model.AppointmentRepository">
</bean> -->
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.cl3</groupId>
 <artifactId>EHealth</artifactId>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>EHealth Maven Webapp</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

 <properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <logback.version>1.0.13</logback.version>
    <jcl-over-slf4j.version>1.7.5</jcl-over-slf4j.version>      
    <hibernate.version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>


 <dependencies>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data /spring-data-jpa -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
<version>1.6.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.1207.jre7</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>


     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.10.Final</version>    
</dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>  
<build>
<finalName>EHealth</finalName>
<plugins>

        <!-- Set JDK Compiler Level -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                <target>${jdk.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- For Tomcat -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/EHealth</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
```

UserRepository.class:
package com.cl3.model;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> 
{
List<User> findByemail(String email);
List<User> findByisdoctor(boolean status);
User findByid(long uid);
}
```

EHealthService.class

```
package com.cl3.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.cl3.model.*;

@Service
public class EHealthService 
{
@Autowired
UserRepository uRepo;


@Autowired
AppointmentRepository aRepo;

@Autowired
NotificationRepository nRepo;


public void registerUser(User u)
{
    uRepo.save(u);
}


public boolean login(User u)
{
    if(uRepo.findByemail(u.getEmail())!=null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

public List<User> getDoctorList()
{
    return uRepo.findByisdoctor(true);
}


public void deleteAppointment(long aid)
{
    Appointment a =aRepo.findByid(aid);
    a.setIscanceled(true);
    Notification n = new Notification();
    n.setAppointmentid(a);
    createNotification(n);

}

public void createNotification(Notification n)
{
    nRepo.save(n);
}


}
```

Comment: Btw ,it would really help if you could show your EHealthService class and also UserRepository (interface)..Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring version - 4.3.8.RELEASE and spring data jpa version - 1.0.2.RELEASE combination worked for me.

If it is version issue then may be you can try this combination.

Answer (score 0):

You have version mismatch problem with BeanUtils.findPropertyForMethod

The below dependency is causing the version problem which is referring to findPropertyForMethod which takes one parameter.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
 <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
 <version>1.6.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Consider changing the version to `2.0.3.RELEASE` which would resolve the issue.

Comment: I am still getting one error:                                                                    INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Feb 14, 2018 11:08:58 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lorg/springframework/beans/factory/access/BeanFactoryReference;